# Authorization Handler with C# Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to use the Policy-based authorization
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies

I have a policy like this

```
p.AddPolicy("GroupMembership", policy =>
{
    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Name);
    policy.AddRequirements(new GroupMemberRequirement(
        ServiceConstants.Admin
    ));
});
```

Although I have the RequireAuthenticatedUser() requirement, the user in my handler is anonymous!

This does **not** work:

```
[Authorize("GroupMembership")]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("About")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> About()
    {
        protected method
    }
```

but this **does** work

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [Authorize("GroupMembership")]
    [HttpGet("About")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> About()
    {
        protected method
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `[Authorize(Policy="GroupMembership")]` ?